# Function to hide/show only one DIV at a time

Tags: javascript, function, sharepoint

I currently have a JavaScript that is looking at a SharePoint list, and pulling back all of the items that meet the criteria in the REST call.

It currently creates DIVs and appends them to a wrapper DIV. The intention of the button is to show/hide the sub-DIVs.

Right now, when I click any of the buttons that are produced, it expands all of the hidden divs. What I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to click each respective button and have its nested div show/hide.

Here is my code:

```js
var listName = "announcement";
var titleField = "Title";
var tipField = "Quote";
var dateFieldFrom = "DateFrom";
var dateFieldTo = "DateTo";
var category = "category";
var noteField = "note";
var query = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=" + titleField + "," + dateFieldTo + "," + dateFieldFrom + "," + category + "," + noteField + "," + tipField;
var today = new Date();
var btnClass = "toggle"
todayString = today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getDate();

//This is the query filter string where we compare the values in the 2 date fields against the current date
query += "&$filter=('" + todayString + "' ge " + dateFieldFrom + " ) and (" + dateFieldTo + " ge '" + todayString + "')";;

var call = $.ajax({
  url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + query,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
  }
});

call.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  var divCount = data.d.results.length;


  for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i++) {

    var tip = data.d.results[i][tipField]; //this is where it looks at the quote field to determine what quote to place in the current dynamically created DIV
    var cat = data.d.results[i][category]; //this is where it looks at the category field to determine what color to style the background of the current dynamically created DIV
    var message = data.d.results[i][noteField];
    var ID = "NewDiv-" + i
    var PID = "P-" + i
    var BID = "btn-" + i

    // Create Message DIV
    var element = document.createElement("div"); //This is the creation of the dynamic DIV
    element.id = ID //This is assigning a DIV an ID            
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tip));
    // Create Inner message DIV
    var innerDiv = document.createElement("div"); // Create a <div> element//New Code 
    innerDiv.id = PID
    innerDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
    // Create button to show/hide the div
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.id = BID
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("show/hide message below"));
    btn.className = btnClass
      // Append Inner DIVs
    document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(element); //This is the parent DIV element that all newly created DIVs get created into
    document.getElementById(ID).appendChild(btn); // Append the button to the newly created DIV
    document.getElementById(ID).appendChild(innerDiv); //This is the message that appears after the newly created DIVs
    if (cat == 'Information') {
      document.getElementById(ID).style.backgroundColor = '#d9edf7'; //Blue Color
      document.getElementById(PID).style.backgroundColor = '#d9edf7'; //Blue Color
      document.getElementById(PID).style.margin = '3px';
      document.getElementById(BID).style.backgroundColor = '#d9edf7';
      document.getElementById(BID).style.border = 'none';
      innerDiv.className = "alert alert-info"
      element.className = "alert alert-info"
    }
    if (cat == 'Warning') {
      document.getElementById(ID).style.backgroundColor = '#fcf8e3'; //Orange Color
      document.getElementById(PID).style.backgroundColor = '#fcf8e3'; //Orange Color
      document.getElementById(PID).style.margin = '3px';
      document.getElementById(BID).style.backgroundColor = '#fcf8e3';
      document.getElementById(BID).style.border = 'none';
      innerDiv.className = "alert alert-warning"
      element.className = "alert alert-warning"
    }
    if (cat == 'Critical') {
      document.getElementById(ID).style.backgroundColor = '#f2dede'; //Red Color
      document.getElementById(PID).style.backgroundColor = '#f2dede'; //Red Color
      document.getElementById(PID).style.margin = '3px';
      document.getElementById(BID).style.backgroundColor = '#f2dede';
      document.getElementById(BID).style.border = 'none';
      innerDiv.className = "alert alert-danger"
      element.className = "alert alert-danger"
    }
  }
  // The below variables and for loop ensure that all sub messages are initially hidden, until the show/hide button is clicked
  var curDiv
  var curID
  for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i++) {
    curID = "P-" + i
    curDiv = document.getElementById(curID)
    curDiv.style.display = 'none';
  }

  // The function below is to assign an event to the button to show/hide the sub message
  var f = function(a) {
    var cDiv
    for (var z = 0; z < divCount; z++) {
      cDiv = "P-" + z
      var div = document.getElementById(cDiv);
      if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
  var idx
  for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
    elems[i].onclick = f;
  }

});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="header"> </div>
```

Comment: I clicked `<>` in the editor for you. Please add the HTML to make it a [mcve] if the duplicate does not help you. Also if you have jQuery, why not use it instead of the DOM methods you have all over the place now? As in `var $element = $("<div/>",{id:ID}).text(tip);`

Comment: sorry about that, there isnt much HTML to show but here it is:

    <div id="wrapper" class="header">

</div>

Comment: i didnt use it because im a noob, and i wasnt sure that it could be used together with JS. I should remove the reference.

Comment: So actually, the AJAX works? If so why post it? If the issue is the buttons, then post a copy of a few JSON elements and have the code generate testable example - replace `query += "&$filter=('" + todayString + "' ge " + dateFieldFrom + " ) and (" + dateFieldTo + " ge '" + todayString + "')";;

var call = $.ajax({
  url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + query,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
  }
});

call.done(` with `var d = {......}`

Comment: Sorry mplungjan, im a noob. I posted all code minus the html intially. Everything works and runs, its just that i dont want all divs to appear when the button is clicked

Comment: and i thank you tremendously for looking at this

Comment: So what you need to do now is to go to your page in Chrome. Right click on the first button and "inspect", then move up to the nearest container. Copy the html. Post it here with just the code `var f = function(a) { ...  }` and `var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
  for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
    elems[i].onclick = f;
  }`

Comment: upon inspecting the element, this is the code that is there:
    <div id="NewDiv-0" class="alert alert-info" style="background-color: rgb(217, 237, 247);">Debbie Teng joins PD Tax!********<button id="btn-0" class="toggle" style="background-color: rgb(217, 237, 247); border: none;">show/hide message below</button><div id="P-0" class="alert alert-info" style="background-color: rgb(217, 237, 247); margin: 3px; display: none;">yadayada1​</div></div>

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all of this - which loops over all divs

```
// The function below is to assign an event to the button to show/hide the sub message
  var f = function(a) {
    var cDiv
    for (var z = 0; z < divCount; z++) {
      cDiv = "P-" + z
      var div = document.getElementById(cDiv);
      if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
  var idx
  for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
    elems[i].onclick = f;
  }
```

with this, it delegates the click on the button in the wrapper and toggles the next object after the button

```
$('#wrapper').on("click",".toggle",function(e) { // notice the delegation
  e.preventDefault(); // in case you forget type="button"
  $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#wrapper').on("click", ".toggle", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="NewDiv-0" class="alert alert-info" style="background-color: rgb(217, 237, 247);">Debbie Teng joins PD Tax!********
    <button id="btn-0" class="toggle" style="background-color: rgb(217, 237, 247); border: none;">show/hide message below</button>
    <div id="P-0" class="alert alert-info" style="background-color: rgb(217, 237, 247); margin: 3px; display: none;">yadayada1​</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to be able to see the trees through the forest :) And now you have learned how to write a better question :)

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning all of your buttons the same onclick function event handler, and that function loops through all the divs and shows them or hides them.

An alternative approach would be to have the event handler toggle only the specific div that's associated with the button.

When you first create the button, you can assign an event handler to it immediately and pass in a reference to the div you want to hide:

```js
var innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
innerDiv.id = PID
innerDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
// Immediately-invoked function expression to attach event handler to inner div:
(function(d){
    btn.onclick = function(){ f(d); };
})(innerDiv);
```

Then just update your `f` function to accept as a parameter the div you want to toggle.

```
// The function below is to assign an event to the button to show/hide the sub message
function f(div){
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can then remove the last few lines of code where you're assigning the buttons to the `elems` collection and looping through it to attach an onclick function.

Comment: Thanks so much Thriggle!

Comment: So the IIFE creates a closure for the f function...Heavy stuff for a noob :)

Comment: @mplungjan I don't disagree, but it's the kind of thing I wished I'd learned sooner than later. In this case it eliminates the need to requery the DOM to re-obtain a reference to an element, as well as the need to load the jQuery library (as long as OP has a suitable replacement for jQuery's `$.ajax` function).

Comment: He does however already have jQuery so `$(this).next().toggle();` is a LOT simpler :) Anyway, thanks for the enlightenment